# Posting a dynamic jquery array using hidden input element to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a list box where users can Add, Delete and Update and Save the list. Once clicked on the Save button I am doing a call to the jquery to build the array of elements in the list box and then doing a POST using a hidden INPUT elememt. But I am getting an empty array the PHP POST. Here is the jquery

```
$("#saveCategory").click (function() {
    var items = $("#jqxlistbox").jqxListBox('getItems');
    var length = items.length; 
    var mylist = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var row = {};
        row["cname"] = items[i].value;
        row["cvalue"] = items[i].label;
        mylist[i] = row;
    }
    $("#myCatgories").value(mylist);  
});
```

here is my html form

```
<form id="addcategory" method="post" action="index.php">
<div style="float: left">
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="addCategory" style="margin-left: 3px" />
        <input type="button" value="Update" id="updateCategory" style="margin-left: 3px" />
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteCategory" style="margin-left: 3px" />
        <br />                                            
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="saveCategory" style="margin-left: 3px" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myCatgories[]" id="myCatgories" value="">
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and put in the right the direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below (there was an issue with your array initialization), and .value() is not a proper jQ method, it should be `.val()`

```
$("#saveCategory").click (function() {
    var items = $("#jqxlistbox").jqxListBox('getItems');
    var length = items.length; 
    var mylist = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var row = [];
        row["cname"] = items[i].value;
        row["cvalue"] = items[i].label;
        mylist[i] = row;
    }
    $("#myCatgories").val(mylist);  
});
```

If this doesn't work, I suggest using `console.log(mylist)` and `console.log(items)` to make sure you are grabbing data and not empty fields.

Comment: I checked and getting the data. the problem is $("#myCatgories").value(mylist); it is giving this error .Value is not a function

Comment: TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
$("#myCatgories").value(mylist);
this is the complete error message getting on the console.

Comment: I change it to $('#myCatgories').value = mylist; 
error gone but still empty array in the POST. Any comments

Comment: @Aamer apologies, I forgot to make the most important correction, to your line of code calling the nonexistent `.value()` method. See my edit for updated code that should work (if not, add a `console.log('#myCategories: ' + $('#myCategories').val()` at the end of the script to confirm the problem is with the POST and not with the JS.

Comment: many thanks for the correction. Got it right after some modification. Post the corrected code

Answer (score 0):

change your input type from submit to button and on its click event ... sumit the form by using `submit()`

try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="saveCategory" style="margin-left: 3px" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#saveCategory").click (function() {
  var items = $("#jqxlistbox").jqxListBox('getItems');
  var length = items.length; 
  var mylist = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var row = {};
    row["cname"] = items[i].value;
    row["cvalue"] = items[i].label;
    mylist[i] = row;
  }
  $("#myCatgories").val(mylist);
  $('#addcategory').submit(); //<-- submit you form here
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to change it from `submit` to `button`. The onclick JS will execute first regardless of input type, and if you don't want to submit the form due to an error, you can always `return false;`. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I changed as you mentioned by still getting an empty array in the POST. Also had to change second last line to
$('#myCatgories').value = mylist; 
to get rid of the error